# Intersection of Hamming balls of boolean vectors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, coding-theory, spheres

I noticed that a similar question was asked with a little difference, an answer to this wasn't given certainly. Here is the problem: Given two Hamming balls of boolean vectors of size $n$ with centres $a$ and $b$ both with radius $r$ find the power of the set of their intersection, that is $|B(a, r)\cap B(b, r)|$ .By a boolean $n$-vector I mean a vector of length $n$ consisting only of $0$'s and $1$'s. I tried to get this number in a closed form but I think it's impossible, so the answer need not be in a closed form. And the Hamming distance between vectors $a$ and $b$ is $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the intersection $S(a,r)\cap S(b,s)$ of two Hamming spheres.
We may assume that $a$ is the zero vector and $$b = (\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{m\text{ times}},\underbrace{0\,\ldots,0}_{n-m\text{ times}}).$$
We want to count the vectors $v$ which are at distance $r$ from $a$ and $s$ from $b$.
Distance $r$ from $a$ means that $v$ has exactly $r$ entries equal $1$.
Distance $s$ from $b$ gives that if in the first $m$ entries of $b$ there are exactly $i$ zeros (i.e. exactly $m-i$ ones), in the last $n-m$ entries there must be exactly $s-i$ ones.
So $(m - i) + (s-i) = r$, implying that $2i = m+s-r$. Hence $m + s - r$ is even, $i = (m+s-r)/2$ and $s - i = (s+r-m)/2$.
Therefore
$$\left|S(a,r)\cap S(b,s)\right| = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }m-(s+r)\text{ odd,}\\\binom{m}{(s-r+m)/2}\binom{n-m}{(s+r-m)/2}&\text{if }m\text{ even.}\end{cases}$$

Now we get the size of the intersection of the two Hamming balls as
$$\left|B(a,r)\cap B(b,r)\right| = \sum_{i=0}^r \sum_{\substack{j=0\\m+i-j\text{ even}}}^r \binom{m}{(i-j+m)/2}\binom{n-m}{(i+j-m)/2}.$$

Comment: The problem is that the distance is <=r which makes this problem a little difficult ,you wrote for a hamming sphere.

Comment: Right, I had thought of the sphere. But in this way we also get the size of the intersection of two Hamming balls, summing over the possible speres.

Comment: Would the formula be different if you didn't assume $a = 0^n$ and $b = 1^m 0^{(n-m)}$? How much harder is the more general question?

Comment: @gen No, the formula is always the same. The assumtion on $a$ and $b$ is not a restriction, as this choice can always be achieved by the application of an isometry of the Hamming space. (From higher point of view: The Hamming metric is distance invariant.)

Comment: @azimut do you mean by distance invariance that the metric is translation invariant $d(x,y) = d(x+a, y+a)$?

Comment: @gen What I meant is "distance transitive". For any $x,y,x',y'$ with $d(x,y) = d(x',y')$ there exists an isometry $\phi$ of the Hamming space with $\phi(x) = x'$ and $\phi(y) = y'$.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't familiar with this notion.

Comment: Also, I think on the right hand side of your first case discrimination the second term in the product should be ${n-m \choose (s+r-m)/2}$ instead of ${n-m \choose (m-s-r)/2}$. This is becuase $i = (m+s-r)/2$ and $(s-i) = (s+r-m)/2$.

Comment: @gen thanks, I think you are right. I did a correction to my answer.